# Filter table of attributes by numerical values (all values between x and y)

Tags: qgis-3, feature-filter

I am trying to select features based on their area (in the column "surface") in the table of attributes.

I wrote: `SELECT "surface" BETWEEN 300 AND 1500`, it doesn't work.
I also tried: `"surface" >300 <1500` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `AND` operator like the following in QGIS expressions:

```
"surface" > 300 AND "surface" < 1500
```

For a virtual layer the SQL would be:

```
select * from layer where "surface" between 300 and 1500
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!